# Consequences of misalignment connection that grounded power supplies

Tags: power-supply, diodes, short-circuit

Having the following mezzanine expansion connector

[image: connector]

and the related +VSYS_IN part of the [schematic](https://www.avnet.com/opasdata/d120001/medias/docus/193/Ultra96-V2%20Rev1%20Schematic.pdf)

[image: main_power]

What would be the consequences of a misaligned connection that shorted both +5V and +VSYS_IN to GND in case the diode D18 was not mounted? And if it is mounted ?

Note: I'm trying to understand the implications of the situation described in the following [post](https://discuss.96boards.org/t/ultra96-safety-missing/7697). The diode was placed in the following revision of the board but it is not clear to me what was the intent and how it can solve the misalignment problem.

Comment: Comments on the linked page (from someone ni the project) say the added diode D19 protects against a different hazard. Is says nothing about D18 which doesn't protect against misalignment, it protects against reversed power connection. Consequences of misalignment shorting power to GND? That all depends on the power supplies : how well are they protected?

Comment: The author of the first post comments that the original problem was that +VSYS_IN and +5.0V got shorted and that the added D18 prevented that short. Does the diode protects in some way about that misalignment?